# Use library Opus-recorder workers in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, create-react-app

I have react app with cra that uses two different things (mapbox-gl and  opus-recorder) my problem is that i used worker-loader to load there needed workers but they  made a conflict with each other;  is there any other way to deal with this issue or is there any way to fix this issue

i tried importing only the opus recorders worker but i ended up by another problem an error with this message  `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`
here is my code for opus recorder

```js
        const options = {
            mimeType: 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus',
            audioBitsPerSecond: 64000,
        };

        const workerOptions = {
            encoderPath: encoderWorker
        };
        //opus instance
        const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options, workerOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found where the problem was. there was no need to load worker files with `worker-loader` it just needed a link i made symlink from pcackage files dist folder to my public folder(sense web pack would not bundle those files) and just passed the encoder file url to my opus recorder options object